# How to count the number of instances per hour when time is not an index in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a data frame caled 'strt' with only a column of datetime and I want to count the number of instances per hour. The DateTime is not index it is specified in a column called DT. So the other solutions that work for counting index do not work.[image: The figure show example of the dataframe called strt with date and time in a calumn called DT]

I have tried
strt_bar= strt.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='DT', freq='H')).count()
but it seems that it works for datetime index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DatetimeIndex` does not mean you have to set it as index. I think the problem is `count` because you have only one column (so there is nothing to count). Try to replace with `size`:

```
>>> df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='DT', freq='H'), as_index=False).count()
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []

>>> df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='DT', freq='H'), as_index=False).size()
                   DT  size
0 2019-02-04 00:00:00    12
1 2019-02-04 01:00:00     8
```

Note: you can also use `df.resample('H', on='DT').size()`

Input data:

```
>>> df
                    DT
0  2019-02-04 00:45:43
1  2019-02-04 00:46:55
2  2019-02-04 00:48:07
3  2019-02-04 00:49:19
4  2019-02-04 00:50:31
5  2019-02-04 00:51:43
6  2019-02-04 00:52:55
7  2019-02-04 00:54:07
8  2019-02-04 00:55:19
9  2019-02-04 00:56:31
10 2019-02-04 00:57:43
11 2019-02-04 00:58:55
12 2019-02-04 01:00:07
13 2019-02-04 01:01:19
14 2019-02-04 01:02:31
15 2019-02-04 01:03:43
16 2019-02-04 01:04:55
17 2019-02-04 01:06:07
18 2019-02-04 01:07:19
19 2019-02-04 01:08:31
```

Comment: I used: strt['DT'] = pd.to_datetime(strt['DT']) to convert data to datetime64 and then your solution worked.

Answer (score 1):

Run:

```
strt_bar = strt.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='DT', freq='H')).size()
```

The result, for your sample data, is:

```
DT
2019-02-04 00:00:00    2
2019-02-04 01:00:00    1
2019-02-04 02:00:00    0
2019-02-04 03:00:00    3
2019-02-04 04:00:00    0
                      ..
2019-02-11 01:00:00    0
2019-02-11 02:00:00    0
2019-02-11 03:00:00    5
2019-02-11 04:00:00    6
2019-02-11 05:00:00    1
Freq: H, Length: 174, dtype: int64
```

Of course, the data type of *DT* column is *datetime64*.

If you want to omit groups with *0* values (for hours
which contain no source data), run:

```
result = strt_bar[strt_bar > 0]
```

This time the result is:

```
DT
2019-02-04 00:00:00    2
2019-02-04 01:00:00    1
2019-02-04 03:00:00    3
2019-02-11 03:00:00    5
2019-02-11 04:00:00    6
2019-02-11 05:00:00    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Isn't it the same logic as in the other answer?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that "Of course, the data type of DT column is datetime64" I used: strt['DT'] = pd.to_datetime(strt['DT']) to convert data to datetime64 and then your solution worked.